# How do you make a non-hashable, C-like enum from a library hashable?

Tags: hash, enums, hashmap, rust

I am learning how to use Rust by making a little Pac-Man clone game in SFML (using RSFML) but I have ran into a problem with mapping the [`Key`](http://www.rust-sfml.org/doc/rsfml/window/keyboard/enum.Key.html) enum.

I have created this struct which has maps of keys tied to booleans, I used this in a previous C++ project so I am just trying to replicate it.

```
use sfml::window::keyboard::Key;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Input {
    held_keys: HashMap<Key, bool>,
    pressed_keys: HashMap<Key, bool>,
    released_keys: HashMap<Key, bool>
}
```

I then received an error about `Key` being not hashable. I checked the library and the enum did not derive `Hash` to make it usable as a key. I looked around for advice about this but did not come with many answers; someone suggested to try and wrap the enum in a new struct type and derive `Hash` from there.

So I tried adding the following:

```
#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct HKey {
     key: Key
}

pub struct Input {
    held_keys: HashMap<HKey, bool>,
    pressed_keys: HashMap<HKey, bool>,
    released_keys: HashMap<HKey, bool>
}
```

But that still ended up with this error, as I am assuming all it does is mix in the hashable trait for each property in the struct.

```
the trait `core::hash::Hash` is not implemented for the type `sfml::window::keyboard::Key`
    key: Key
    ^~~~~~~~
in this expansion of #[derive_Hash] (defined in src/input.rs)
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: required by `core::hash::Hash::hash`
```

I now am guessing I need to try and manually add the `Hash` trait implementation to the new `HKey` struct I made but I don't know how to generate a hash from an enum, as it seems it is not easy to turn it into an int. I ideally want do it safely, if Rust allows it. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

[I am uploading my progress to GitHub, if you need a bigger picture.](https://github.com/Giacom/Rust-Man/blob/master/src/input.rs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Key`](http://www.rust-sfml.org/doc/rsfml/window/keyboard/enum.Key.html) enum is a C-like enum (i.e. no variants have additional data), so we can use `as` to convert an enum of this type to an integer, e.g. `u32`. Then, we can defer to `u32`'s implementation of `Hash`.

Here's a minimal example that doesn't use external libraries:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum E {
    A, B, C
}

struct NE(E);

impl Hash for NE {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) where H: Hasher {
        (self.0 as u32).hash(state)
    }
}
```

`E` doesn't implement `Hash`. `NE` wraps an `E` and implements `Hash` by converting the enum to `u32`, then using `u32`'s implementation of `Hash`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Then you cry.

Comment: Thanks Francis. I did not know you could convert an enum with 'as'. I managed to implement it into my code with no problems.